# Seaborn Heatmap Key Words

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

I cannot find any documentation about the key words in seaborn heat maps for either `annot_kws` or `cbar_kws`.

Is there a secret place where I can find such things?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is little to no documentation at that location for annot_kws or cbar_kws.

Comment: Sorry for the unfair comment yesterday, I did no read your question properly.

Comment: No problem. Your apology is a testament to your good character. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [docstring](https://stanford.edu/%7Emwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) of heatmap  tells you:

> **annot_kws** : dict of key, value mappings, optional
> Keyword arguments for ax.text when annot is True.

> **cbar_kws** : dict of key, value mappings, optional
> Keyword arguments for fig.colorbar.

That means that those dictionaries pass keyword arguments directly to the underlying `matplotlib` structures.

`annot_kws` are keywords for `ax.text`, `cbar_kws` are keywords for `fig.colorbar`.

So in order to find out possible arguments you have to look into the `matplotlib` documentation for these objects.

[Here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) is the documentation of `figure.colorbar`.

[Here](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.text) is the documentation of `axis.text`, which gives you a link where you can find an explanation for the keyword arguments.

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks!

Comment: So for 'ticks' in cbar_kws, the MPL documentation says: ticks [ None | list of ticks | Locator object ] If None, ticks are determined automatically from the input.   I tried cbar_kws{'ticks':['a','b','c','d']} where 4 ticks were usually displayed and received the error: TypeError: colorbar() got multiple values for keyword argument 'ticks' I tried changing the number and type of tick labels to no avail. An ideas?

Comment: @DanceParty2, so what happens in seaborn is this: `cb = ax.figure.colorbar(mesh, cax, ax, ticks=ticker, **self.cbar_kws)` - So basically the code creates the colorbar and already sets the ticks via keyword argument. So you cannot add the keyword `ticks` in `cbar_kws`, because otherwise you would have it twice in the call of `ax.figure.colorbar` and python cannot handle that. I am not sure if it is actually possible to work around that limitation.

Comment: Interesting. I found some work on it on GitHub: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/459  and it looks like some progress was made as of June but I'm not sure if it's something that can be incorporated into the library. @mwaskwam ?

Comment: colorbar docs have moved: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=colorbar#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar

Comment: And they moved again: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html